Upgrade software on multiple machines using some form of caching
I have about 60 machines that I need to run sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade on, I've written a script to perform this action, but each machine is taking about 30-40 minutes due to a very slow LTE/Cellular/Mobile internet connection (it's a remote location).
As I was doing this, I was wondering if there was a way to cache the downloads done by each upgrade, so that the next machine can use the cached file (from a local location) rather than downloading it again.
I know that Microsoft Windows has an option called Allow Downloads from other PCs which is roughly what I need.
I was thinking that if there was a mirror set up locally that either downloaded from the requested URL, or returned the cached file, that would speed things up massively.
edit
The local network is a mixture of Ubuntu Server v24.04.1 and Raspberry PI 5. I was hoping to use one of the Ubuntu machines as the 'cache server'.

There is no mention of Ubuntu in this question. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Is it server or desktops? Please edit the question and add this info, not as a comment.

it's actually a mixture of Ubuntu and Raspberry PIs, the Ubuntu version is 24.04.1, I was hoping to configure one of the Ubuntu machines as the proxy/cache. I assumed that the mechanism for apt upgrade would be the same across Linux machines

I used apt-cacher-ng for this.
In this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1503211/243321 I explain some details about how I set it up. The question there is not a duplicate but IMHO contains valuable tips about how to get it working.
I have not yet managed to successfully cache https repos yet however.
I don't know about Raspberry pi's but this single setup successfully caches updates for two different Ubuntu versions (20.04 and 22.04) although it runs on a 20.04 box.
